# How to get country code by using CoreTelephony in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios16, core-telephony

I am using CoreTelephony for get country code from the sim in the iOS device.

I have seen the discussion [here](https://l1nq.com/SdxXa). But isoCountryCode is deprecated from ios 16 onwards. I got key(0000000100000001) from serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology, and pass the key through serviceSubscriberCellularProviders.

This is the code:

```
if #available(iOS 12.0, *){
    if let providers = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology {    
        providers.forEach { (key, value) in
            if let temp:[String:CTCarrier] = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders{
                if let simData:CTCarrier = temp[key]{
                    let code:String = simData.isoCountryCode ?? "no data"
                    print(code)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and got an output like this because the testing device is in ios 16.

### --

Is there any way to get country code from the SIM.

Comment: No, there is not any other way to get the country code from the sim. The CTCarrier which gives the information regarding to the operator is deprecated and this is  related to the user's privacy. That's why CTCarrier is deprecated. And for more information you may visit the developer forum queries https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714876.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, It shows "Deprecated with no replacement".